# Wordpress internal links only working for me and no one else

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hello this is my first time posting and I wanted to quickly thank everyone on this site for the help they provide before jumping into my query.

My wordpress site is acting really odd and I cannot place my finger onto it as to why it is doing what it is. For me only, on my personal google chrome account I can access the website and all its pages like any other website. However if I use a different google chrome account or a mobile phone, I can go to the website but I cannot click on any of the posts links. Only a few external links work on the site.

I recently was approved by Google for their Adsense program and after I had inserted my first ad I noticed that I could no longer click on my website pages. I have since removed those adverts but the website still does not work for anyone else but myself.

I have deactivated every single plugin one by one to see which one is causing the issue but to no avail. The weird thing though is though, when I installed a couple of plugins such as yoast and refreshed my site, it would take me to the post that I was trying to click on before I deactivated the plugin.

I do not know anything about coding to 'look underneath the bonnet' so I am really stuck here.

EDIT: Website is DBZ-Club.com

Comment: Without a link it is difficult to say what the problem is. Could you perhaps give us a link to the website?

Comment: Sorry, I've just put the link of the website in.

Comment: I would guess that you have a script preventing default behavior on click of `anchor` tags, because the links work fine if I right-click them and open them in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out that it was in fact one of my plugins that had caused the issues to my site. It was the MonsterInsights plugin used to track your Google Analytics, they came with an update this morning and it looks like it has fixed the site.

The reason it did not fix my site when I deactivated the plugin is because for some reason there's 5 minute lag before changes occur on my site most likely due to my Cache Plugin.